# Prime numbers dividing the orders of the sporadic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, prime-numbers

When we consider the list of the prime numbers that divide the order of the 26 (or 27 if you include Tits  group T) sporadic groups, we find that they all are among the 20 smallest prime numbers.
In fact, the order of the monster sporadic group M is divided by the 15 following primes:
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 41, 47, 59 and 71.
Moreover, the order of the sporadic group J4 is divided by: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 23, 29, 31, 37 and 43,
and the order of the sporadic group Ly is divided by 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 31, 37 and 67.
So that, because no other prime is dividing the order of another sporadic group, we find that
considering the list of the 20 smallest prime numbers, only the 16th prime, 53, and the 19th prime, 61, are omitted of the list of the divisors of the orders of the sporadic groups.
Do we know an explanation for this curious fact ?
Gérard Lang

Comment: For the Monster group the primes are called supersingular and have an interpretation in terms of elliptic curves: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_prime_(moonshine_theory) .  I think there are nascent moonshine theories associated to some of the other sporadic groups but nothing concrete.

Comment: This question is of the same type as "why 3 divides 9 and 2 does not?". Voted to close. 

Comment: There does not seem to be a uniform theory of sporadic groups (yet), so I think the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: As Qiaochu points out, primes dividing the order of the Monster group were observed several decades ago by Andrew Ogg to have a strange correlation with elliptic modular forms.   Similar observations for the entire collection of sporadic simple groups would certainly arouse interest, but in the meantime the answer to your question is "no" as Scott concludes.

Comment: Just because the answer to this question is "no" doesn't mean it should be closed. A "yes" answer would be incredibly interesting, and it's not too low-level to be asked.

Comment: With Mark, I don't understand what this curious 'fact' actually is.  Do 53 and 61 have something in common?

Comment: Numerology questions are extremely popular on MO. I just wonder about our famous prime 163: where is it in this story?!

Comment: For me the sporadic simple groups are non-trivial structures of great interest. It is not clear whether there is any connection between the groups and the primes at a deeper level. A finite set (orders of groups) is necessarily bounded - but it is not trivial that the number of sporadic groups is finite. It seems to me that the question might also be of interest the other way round. Is there any feature of the small primes which "explains" the fact that there are finitely many sporadic simple groups?

Comment: Thanks to all. At least, we have a partial answer concerning the Monster sporadic group that is a plain mathematical result, and seem to owe nothing to numerology. So, why could not we hope to find a global answer with a collective result on all sporadic groups?
Gérard Lang

Comment: You can hope all you want, the problem is that there is no global theory for sporadic simple groups.  Just as a general rule, most facts about simple groups don't have "global" explanations, but involve some kind of case analysis.  Look, for example, at the odd order theorem, which is one of the better "global" results of this type.

Comment: A theory of the Monster could still deal with most of the sporadics, as all except six of them are sections of the Monster.  But as far as I know, the remaining 'pariahs' are still a total mystery.

Comment: Recently, a 'moonshine' phenomenon involving the Mathieu group $M_{24}$ has been observed by Eguchi-Ooguri-Tachikawa. Of course, $M_{24}$ is a section of the Monster. 

Answer (score 2):

A trivial remark: Since the number of these primes is less than the number of sporadic groups, the multiplicative subgroup of ${\mathbb Q}^{\times}$ generated by the orders of sporadic groups is not free on 26 (or 27) generators. :-).